# Function 'fzero' in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How do I solve the following problem?

Equation:

```
1/f^0.5 = -2log(0.011 + 1/((1.3*10^-5)(f^0.5))
```

Solve for f using the [fzero](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/matlab/techdoc/ref/fzero.html) function in MATLAB.

Comment: Not related, but I feel like I should be racing right now =D Vroom Vroom fzero!

Answer (score 0):

Define a function as:

```
func1 =@(f) 1/f^0.5 + 2*log(0.011 + 1/((1.3*10^-5)*(f^0.5));
```

Then do `fzero(func1, x0);`. It's not rocket science, but you'll need to find a value of `x0` for it to start with. Try 1eN, with N left as an exercise.